# how to give color only telephone code like +91 or 022 in phone number in ms excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have number of data which has phone and mobile number in excel. tell me how to give specific color like red to phone code. for example 022-1234567 or +91-1234567890. Please tell me how to color only +91 and 022 in excel for the entire column or single cells only.

```
Sub Macro1() 
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.Value 
With ActiveCell
 .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=0)
 .Font 
 .Name = "Arial" 
 .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone 
End With 
With ActiveCell
 .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3) 
 .Font 
 .OutlineFont = False 
 .Shadow = False 
 .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone 
 .Color = -16776961 
 .TintAndShade = 0 
 .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone 
End With End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional formatting

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: If you want specific help, you also need to be specific about what version of Excel.

Comment: Sub Macro1()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.Value
        With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=0).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
End Sub

Comment: I have created above. I really need to show my manager at any cost today. please advice how to count characters length till "-"

Comment: Seriously - "at any cost" - just google "conditional formatting" for excel. It's really simple. Hell - we have a [conditional formatting tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting) here at SuperUser. -1

Answer (score 0):

If we start with:

[image]

and run this short macro:

```
Sub ColorMeRed()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, v As String
    Dim i As Long
    Set rng = Range("B1:B10")

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        i = InStr(v, "-")
        If i > 0 Then
            r.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=i - 1).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

We end up with:

[image]